AC Stepdown transformer blown troubleshoot
I've had a ring doorbell pro for about 5 years, it's wired directly to the following transformer output 1 & 4 (24v):

It's using the original doorbell wiring, which rightly or wrongly, was wired off the ground floor lighting circuit/breaker.
I replaced a light on the ground floor with an LED panel, turning off at the breaker first.
After installing the light, and turning the breaker back on, the light / lighting all works fine, but the transformer never came back on.
Checking with a multimeter, it's getting 240v at the primary, but it's not humming / nothing coming out of the secondary.
After removing the transformer, and checking the resistance across the primary, I'm getting nothing. So seems like a protection fuse or winding has burnt out open circuit.
Question:
What would cause a transformer to fail across the primary, from simply switching a breaker off, then back on?
I've ordered a replacement transformer, but feel like I need to get to the bottom of why the original one would fail in the first place!


What would cause a transformer to fail across the primary, from simply switching a breaker off, then back on?

It cooled down when the breaker went off then, it warmed up when the breaker was activated again. I'd say this was a small thermal transient that was the straw that broke the camel's back. This sort of thing happens now and then.
There is also another issue with transformers to consider and that's inrush current.
Transformers "prefer" to be activated at the peak of the voltage cycle because this prevents a significant inrush current compared to being activated at the zero-crossing-point of the voltage. It sounds counter-intuitive but it's all about how the magnetic flux is formed.
When activated at the voltage-zero-cross nearly twice the flux density is produced for several cycles of AC and the peak current can be a lot more than twice if the core begins to heavily saturate on the doubled flux.

Thanks for the reply Andy! So the first part of your answer indicates it's just a common failure with transformers.  Would that be something like a solder joint coming apart due to the thermal cycle?
Regarding second part, is there anything I can do to protect the replacement transformer from inrush current?

@JamesWilliams unfortunately there's nothing reasonably simple that can be done.

interestingly, after taking the transformer apart, I got no continuity. After tugging on the wires a bit trying to get the transformer out of the housing, suddenly got continuity  again. The unit is damaged now, but looks like the clamp around the wires at the primary input has oxidised / burnt a little,. Which makes me think the thermal cycling you mentioned caused it's final failure
